# Running javascript in Electron Secondary Window

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js, electron

I have created an electron application that has multiple windows that can open ex. an about page and a preferences page. This is what my main.js looks like.

```
const {app, Tray, Menu, BrowserWindow} = require('electron'); 
//electron application stuff
const path = require('path'); //allows for use of path
const url = require('url'); //allows for loadURL and url.format
const iconPath = path.join(__dirname, 'icon.png'); //grab the icon
let tray = null; //set the tray to null
let win = null; //set the main window to null

app.on('ready', function(){
 win = new BrowserWindow({width: 600, height: 400, resizable: false}); 
 //create main window

 win.setMenu(null); //the main window had no menu
 win.loadURL(url.format({    //loads the webpage for the main window
 pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
protocol: 'file:',
slashes: true
}))
win.openDevTools(); //starts the application with developer tools open

win.on('minimize',function(event){ //prevents standard minimize 
function of a main window
    event.preventDefault()
        win.hide();
});
win.on('close', function (event) { //prevents the closing of the 
aplication when the window closes
    if( !app.isQuiting){
        event.preventDefault()
        win.hide();
    }
    return false;
});
tray = new Tray(iconPath); //create a new tray
var contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([  //start buliding out the 
menu for the tray

      { label: 'Insomnia', click:  function(){  //makes the main window reappear
          win.show();
      } },
      { label: 'About', click:  function(){ //shows the about window
        abt = new BrowserWindow({width: 400, height: 400, resizable: false});
        abt.setMenu(null); //the about window has no menu
        abt.loadURL(url.format({  //loads the webpage for the about window
          pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'about.html'),
          protocol: 'file:',
          slashes: true
        }))

      } },
      {
        label: 'Preferences', click:  function(){ //shows the about window
          pref = new BrowserWindow({width: 400, height: 400, resizable: false});
          pref.setMenu(null); //the about window has no menu
          pref.loadURL(url.format({  //loads the webpage for the about window
            pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'preferences.html'),
            protocol: 'file:',
            slashes: true
          }))

        }
      },
      { label: 'Quit', click:  function(){ //quit the application
          app.isQuiting = true;
          app.quit(); //quit called

      } }
  ]);
tray.setToolTip('Insomnia'); //Honestly no clue but itll make the tray 
say insomnia in some other place
tray.setContextMenu(contextMenu); //attach the menu to the tray
});
```

When the user opens the preferences window I have a button there that lets them store their preferences. When i use scripts from the java script file on win window they actually work. However using that same logic for the preferences window none of the java script functions actually run. This is what my preferences.html looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Preferences</title>
   </head>
   <body BGCOLOR="#02D9CC" >
      </div>
      <center> <img src="sleep.png" alt="sleep" style="width:100px;height:100px;"> </center>
      <div style="position:absolute;bottom:250px;margin-left:110px">
      <center>
        <input onclick="storeTimePreference()" type="radio" id="timeType" name="timeType" value="Military"> Military </input>
        <input onclick="storeTimePreference()" type="radio" id ="timeType2" name="timeType" value="Standard" checked="checked"> Standard </input>
      </center>
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;bottom:150px;margin-left:110px">
      <center><input type="time" id="defaultTime" /><br>
         <button onlick="readFile()" >Set Default Wake Up Time</button>
      </center>
    </div>
      <div class ="version" style="position:absolute;bottom:5px;color:white;margin-left:225px">
      <center >
        Insomnia Version 1.0.0

      </center>
    </div>
    <script src="./js/script.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Where the readFile() script and storeTimePreference() functions are both part of the script.js included at the bottom. Which is the same way i did it for the index.html however here it doesn't work and I'm not sure why. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong here or why this doesn't work and what a workaround would be?